# Revoke-AzureADUserAllRefreshToken CommandNotRecognized

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory

I'm trying to run the following script to disable AD and O365 accounts that are disabled.

```
import-module activedirectory
$Corporate = Get-ADUser -Server "myActiveDirectoryDomain" -Filter * -Property Enabled | Where-Object {$_.Enabled -like “false”}
$Corporate | ForEach-Object -Process { Revoke-AzureADUserAllRefreshToken -ObjectId $_.ObjectGUID }
```

However, when I run my script, I get this errror...

```
Revoke-AzureADUserAllRefreshToken : The term 'Revoke-AzureADUserAllRefreshToken' is not recognized as the name of a 
cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that 
the path is correct and try again.
At C:\Users\lpurhr1\Documents\_RHR\PowerShellScripts\RemoveAccessTokenForDisabledAccounts.ps1:37 char:40
+ ... | ForEach-Object -Process { Revoke-AzureADUserAllRefreshToken -Object ...
+                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Revoke-AzureADUserAllRefreshToken:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I have no idea why I'm getting this error, and nothing online is really telling me why this should be happening. I can run the Get-ADUser cmdlet just fine, but the Revoke-AzureADUserAllRefreshToken doesn't seem to be recognized. I'm sure there's something I'm not installing. Does anyone know what I'm missing?

Comment: my understanding is that the `Azure*` and the [newer?] `Az*` cmdlets are NOT part of the `activedirectory` module. so ... have you installed the required module? is it available to the account that is running the code in question?

Comment: The module I installed is located here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=45520...

It's called: WindowsTH-RSAT_WS_1803-x64.msu...

Originally, I was instructed to add the Optional Feature: RSAT Active Directory Domain Services and Lightweight Directory Services Tools...

However, Windows 10 never let me install them; it always got stuck at a 6% on the download. Help Desk helped me install with that MSU file.
After installing on that file, the RSAT tools were not there, but I could now call "Get-ADUser" correctly where before I couldn't.

Comment: that is NOT the AZ module [the newer one], nor is it the Azure module. both require that you install them before you use them. >>> Install Azure PowerShell with PowerShellGet | Microsoft Docs — https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/install-az-ps?view=azps-4.2.0 <<< and >>> Introducing the Azure PowerShell Az module | Microsoft Docs — https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/new-azureps-module-az?view=azps-4.2.0 <<< install only one of them! [*grin*]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command [`Revoke-AzureADUserAllRefreshToken`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/revoke-azureaduserallrefreshtoken?view=azureadps-2.0) belongs to the `AzureAD` powershell module, you need to install it first.

```
Install-Module AzureAD
```

Reference - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/active-directory/install-adv2?view=azureadps-2.0

Comment: I had to run this in administrator mode, but that seems to have done the trick.